# Password Hashing with bcryptjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, bcrypt, password-encryption

I'm currently trying to recreate a bcrypt tutorial for password hashing (in node.js with express) I recently found (as shown below):

```
var password = 'A very normal Password';
   bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function(err, hash) {
      if (!err) {
         console.log('Hash: ' + hash);
      } else {
         console.log('Error: ' + err);
      }
    });
```

The hashing works correctly with a pre-set password. But I'm using Textfields, which I'm referring to with body-parser:

```
var email = req.body.email;
var password = req.body.password;
    bcrypt.hash(password,10,function (err, hash) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log('Hash: ' + hash);
        } else{
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        }
    });
```

I'm sending a router.post() request to the Server on my route ('/register') to retrieve the typed in PW from the textfield. But when I run my server, it instantly gives out a hash, without even filling the textfield.

How can I hash the input from the textfield?

P.S.: Is bcrypt the best way to hash PWs? Or should I use something else?

Comment: _without even filling the textfield_ how should your backend fill a frontend textfield?

Comment: Here's [a good discussion on bcrypt](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage) at [security.se] (old, but still relevant).

Comment: @baao It should do the hash after I filled the textfields, then save it into my DB

Comment: @msanford I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please try it, I think your problem solved

var password = 'A very normal Password';
var hashPassword= bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10)